# useState: destructure nested object with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to destructure an object in `useState` so I can directly use the properties.
But I am not sure about the correct syntax to use with typescript.

Here is the interface for "topic":

```
export interface ITopic{
    title: string
    text?: string
    posts?: string[]
}
```

Without destructuring it would look like:

```
const [topic, setTopic] = useState<ITopic>()
```

To destructure, I have tried a few things,for instance this doesn't work:

```
const [{title, text, posts}: ITopic, setTopic] = useState<ITopic>();
```

It says (if I hover over title and setTopic):

- Property 'title' does not exist on type 'ITopic | undefined'
- Tuple type '[ITopic | undefined, Dispatch<SetStateAction<ITopic | undefined>>]' of length '2' has no element at index '2'.

Comment: the initial value of the state is undefined. why are you trying to desctructing undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an initial value. Because you don't have an initial value, it detects on the first render that this cannot be destructured.

```
export interface ITopic{
    title: string
    text?: string
    posts?: string[]
}

const [{title, text, posts}, setTopic] = useState<ITopic>({
    posts: [],
    text: '',
    title: ''
});
```

Comment: Might want to reword problem 1 to be more clear? In any case, optional properties aren't the cause of this error, but they should be removed anyways if you are going to provide an initial value.

Comment: @caTS That being said, I was wrong about the optional properties. I removed that portion from my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The second approach is to add a check in the forms of loading data:

```
const [topic, setTopic] = useState<ITopic | undefined>() 
// explicitly define the type as "undefined", which is unnecessary, but a good indicator

if(!topic) return <div>loading</div>;

const {title, text, posts} = topic; // then you can safely destructure the object
```